# Android AutoCompleteTextView - How to add the searched data is not available in the list?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am working with AutoCompleteTextView.I am able to do search.But i need to do like when am typing something may be it will not be in the list.So i need to show that in to my drop down list(like web) and also when i choose from the list the typed thing need to be removed from the drop down list.
For example,

Step 1:

[image: normal list]

Step 2:
[image: the typed data not in the list]
Step 3:
Again we select like the first step need to be remove from the list.

The following i have tried so far,

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AutoCompleteTextView machineNameAT;
    ArrayList<MachineNameModel> machineNameArrayList;
    MachineNameAutoCompleteAdapter machineNameAutoCompleteAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        machineNameArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        machineNameAT = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.machineNameAT);
        machineNameAT.setThreshold(1);
        MachineNameModel machineNameModel=new MachineNameModel("1","101","1001","LAPTOP","000.000.000.001");
        machineNameArrayList.add(machineNameModel);
        MachineNameModel machineNameModel1=new MachineNameModel("2","102","1002","MOBILE","000.000.000.002");
        machineNameArrayList.add(machineNameModel1);
        MachineNameModel machineNameModel2=new MachineNameModel("3","103","1003","PRINTER","000.000.000.003");
        machineNameArrayList.add(machineNameModel2);
        machineNameAutoCompleteAdapter = new MachineNameAutoCompleteAdapter(this,R.layout.machine_name_item, machineNameArrayList);
        machineNameAT.setAdapter(machineNameAutoCompleteAdapter);
        machineNameAutoCompleteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        machineNameAT.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus)
                    machineNameAT.showDropDown();


            }
        });

        machineNameAT.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                machineNameAT.showDropDown();
                return false;
            }
        });
               machineNameAT.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            machineNameAT.showDropDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if(machineNameArrayList.contains(machineNameAT.getText().toString())){
                machineNameAutoCompleteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                machineNameAT.showDropDown();
            }else{
                MachineNameModel machineNameModel1=new MachineNameModel("","","",machineNameAT.getText().toString(),"");
                machineNameArrayList.add(machineNameModel1);

                machineNameAutoCompleteAdapter = new MachineNameAutoCompleteAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.machine_name_item, machineNameArrayList);
                machineNameAT.setAdapter(machineNameAutoCompleteAdapter);
                machineNameAutoCompleteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                machineNameAT.showDropDown();
            }
        }
    });

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete)

Comment: is that any possibility to do without library

Comment: @RohanStark but there is a index na @....can you tell me how can i replace that in adapter

Comment: Where is the index?

Comment: in th ladapter  Subclass TokenCompleteTextView

Comment: From what I understand, you can use the [getOnItemSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#getOnItemSelectedListener()) to remove the entry from your list whenever you select it.

Comment: However, you'd still have to implement a way to put it back in the list if the user wants to deselect it.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with `AutoCompleteTextView`, so I'm sorry but I won't be able to help you much! The library seemed easy to implement and useful, so I shared it with you.

Comment: The lib is different.That is for email address i need to search and add all kind of data